# Remove Items from sub list matching another sub list with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes ( simplified ):

```
public class SeguradoraCalculo
{
    public int CodigoSeguradora { get; set; }

    public List<Franquia> Franquias{get;set;}

}

public class Franquia {
    public int CodFranquia{get;set;}
}
```

And i have the following data:

```
 var allData = new List<SeguradoraCalculo>(){new SeguradoraCalculo(){
                        CodigoSeguradora = 11,
                        Franquias = new List<Franquia>()
                        {
                            new Franquia()
                            {                   
                                CodigoFranquia = 1
                            },
                            new Franquia()
                            {                            
                                CodigoFranquia = 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

    var except = new List<SeguradoraCalculo>()
                {
                    new SeguradoraCalculo()
                    {
                        CodigoSeguradora = 11,
                        Franquias = new List<Franquia>()
                        {
                            new Franquia()
                            {                   
                                CodigoFranquia = 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

How can i have a result that, removing items that match `CodigoSeguradora` and `CodigoFranquia`, existing Franquias are removed and i get `SeguradoraCalculo` only if i have at least one `Franquia` in my `Franquias` List?

In this example my final list would be:

```
            CodigoSeguradora = 11,
            Franquias = new List<Franquia>()
            {
                new Franquia()
                {                            
                    CodigoFranquia = 2
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First join the two collections, based on the key, then go through each joined pair and remove all items from the first that are contained in the second:

```
var query = allData.Join(except,
    item => item.CodigoSeguradora,
    item => item.CodigoSeguradora,
    (a, b) => new { a, b });

foreach (var pair in query)
    pair.a.Franquias.RemoveAll(f => 
        pair.b.Franquias.Select(x => x.CodFranquia).Contains(f.CodFranquia));
```

Comment: I think you need to add something so it knows to compare the `int CodFranquia` values inside the `Franquias`.

Comment: @DavidFreire What *do* you want to do then?  Find the items that should remain?  If so, just call `Except` on the two sequences.

Comment: Yes @Servy, that is correct. Can you please provide more details about that implementation?

Comment: @DavidFreire I'm confident that you can make the small refactor needed to adjust this code to use that method.  It is a very small change at this point.